# Multi client chat application

Tags: java, socket, chat

I want this code to be reviewed, please.

**chatServer.java**

```
    import java.net.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;

    class chatServer {
        static Vector<Socket> ClientSockets;
        static Vector<String> LoginNames;

        chatServer() throws Exception {
            ServerSocket soc = new ServerSocket(12333);
            ClientSockets = new Vector<Socket>();
            LoginNames = new Vector<String>();

            while(true){
                Socket CSoc = soc.accept();
                System.out.println("Client Connected");
                AcceptClient obClient = new AcceptClient(CSoc);
            }
        }
        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
            chatServer ob = new chatServer();
        }

    class AcceptClient extends Thread {
        Socket ClientSocket;
        DataInputStream din;
        DataOutputStream dout;

        AcceptClient (Socket CSoc) throws Exception {
            ClientSocket = CSoc;
            din = new DataInputStream(ClientSocket.getInputStream());
            dout = new DataOutputStream(ClientSocket.getOutputStream());

            String LoginName = din.readUTF();
            System.out.println("User Logged In :" + LoginName);
            LoginNames.add(LoginName);
            ClientSockets.add(ClientSocket);    
            start();
        }

        public void run(){
            while(true){
                try{
                    String msgFromClient = new String();
                    msgFromClient = din.readUTF();
                    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(msgFromClient);
                    String Sendto = st.nextToken();             
                    String MsgType = st.nextToken();

                    int iCount = 0;
                    if(MsgType.equals("LOGOUT")){
                        for(iCount=0; iCount<LoginNames.size(); iCount++){
                            if(LoginNames.elementAt(iCount).equals(Sendto)){
                                LoginNames.removeElementAt(iCount);
                                ClientSockets.removeElementAt(iCount);
                                System.out.println("User " + Sendto +" Logged Out ...");
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    else{
                        String msg="";
                        while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
                            msg = msg+" " +st.nextToken();
                        }
                        for(iCount=0;iCount<LoginNames.size();iCount++){
                            if(LoginNames.elementAt(iCount).equals(Sendto)){    
                                Socket tSoc=(Socket)ClientSockets.elementAt(iCount);                            
                                DataOutputStream tdout=new DataOutputStream(tSoc.getOutputStream());
                                tdout.writeUTF(msg);                            
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                        if(iCount==LoginNames.size()){
                            dout.writeUTF("I am offline");
                        }
                        else{

                        }
                    }
                    if(MsgType.equals("LOGOUT")){
                        break;
                    }

                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }



            }       
        }
    }
    }
```

**chatClient.java**

```
    import java.net.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.util.*;

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    class chatClient extends Frame implements Runnable {
        Socket soc; 
        TextField tf;
        TextArea ta;
        Button btnSend,btnClose;
        String sendTo;
        String LoginName;
        Thread t = null;
        DataOutputStream dout;
        DataInputStream din;

        chatClient(String LoginName,String chatwith) throws Exception {
            super(LoginName);
            this.LoginName = LoginName;
            sendTo = chatwith;
            tf = new TextField(50);
            ta = new TextArea(50,50);
            btnSend = new Button("Send");
            btnClose = new Button("Close");
            soc = new Socket("localhost",12333);

            din = new DataInputStream(soc.getInputStream()); 
            dout = new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());     
            dout.writeUTF(LoginName);

            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        void setup()
        {
            setSize(600,400);
            setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
            add(ta);
            Panel p = new Panel();

            p.add(tf);
            p.add(btnSend);
            p.add(btnClose);
            add(p);
            show();     
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public boolean action(Event e,Object o){
            if(e.arg.equals("Send")){
                try{
                    dout.writeUTF(sendTo + " "  + "DATA" + " " + tf.getText().toString());          
                    ta.append("\n" + LoginName + " Says:" + tf.getText().toString());   
                    tf.setText("");
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }   
            }
            else if(e.arg.equals("Close")){
                try{
                    dout.writeUTF(LoginName + " LOGOUT");
                    System.exit(1);
                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            return super.action(e, o);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
            chatClient Client1 = new chatClient(args[0],args[1]);
            Client1.setup();                
        }   
        public void run(){      
            while(true){
                try{
                    ta.append( "\n" + sendTo + " Says :" + din.readUTF());

                }
                catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Code Review. Please add more context to your question, such as what your code does, and your major concerns.

Comment: To make life easier for reviewers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. See also [this meta question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226/code-should-include-a-description-of-what-the-code-does)

Answer (score 4):

- Java's common naming conventions are that names of types are in PascalCase, and names of variables are in camelCase.
- If `chatServer` is your entry point, the class should be declared as `public`.

Now, for more substantial issues:

- **You should not need `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` in new code.**

  Every deprecated bit of functionality either has a modern equivalent, or *shouldn't be done*.  Particularly in a project this small, there's no good reason for not eliminating the actual *reason* for the warnings. Rather than slapping an annotation on and calling it a day, **get rid of the deprecated stuff.**

  For example, in your client's `setup()` method, you call `show()`. A quick look at the [API docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) will reveal that `show()` is deprecated, having been replaced by `setVisible(true)`. And you shouldn't be using `java.awt.Event` in an app that was written since 1.1.
- **Exceptions exist for a reason. Don't just sweep them under the rug.**

  When code throws an exception, it has run into a problem serious enough to keep it from doing its job.<sup>1</sup> The exception is basically the code's suggestion that the problem is so serious that if the app can't handle the problem, it should die.  If you don't know what's wrong (and you in particular *can't* know, because you're catching *the least specific exception type possible*), then at the very least, you need to clean up any mess you can and get the app back into a known working state.

  In the server's client threads, for example, you'd want to end the connection. The exception could have come from socket I/O -- in which case that socket may never work again, and every iteration from then on is likely to cause the same error.

  Don't catch an exception unless either you know it's not serious,<sup>1</sup> or you intend to *handle* it.  And i mean more than just printing a stack trace and continuing on your merry way.  That's not *handling* exceptions, that's "handling" exceptions.
- As for your `throws` clauses...short of `throws Throwable`, they couldn't be more vague.  It should be obvious which exceptions i can expect.
- **Constructors construct. That's it.**

  They should only get the object into a known, usable state.  More than that is usually a bad idea.  You certainly shouldn't be looping forever inside `chatServer`'s constructor -- til the constructor's done, you technically have a half-baked object.  (And since the class isn't `final`, you can have subclasses, but they can't initialize anything, because the constructor doesn't return.)

  Stick the server's main loop into a `run()` method or something, so you can run it after your object is fully constructed.
- **Avoid extending `Thread` unless you're inventing a new threading model.** Prefer to implement `Runnable` instead.
- IMO, A Thread should not be starting itself.  Let the server decide when to start it.
- I'm a bit willied by the liberties that your threads are taking with the server and with `System.out`.  If you want them to generate output, consider passing them a stream they can output to.  If you want them to mess with the server, give them an API they can use. (But perhaps they shouldn't be messing with the server at all.  They seem to do so solely to record their existence -- which seems more like a job for the server itself.)
- **The whole deal with `ClientSockets` and `LoginNames` is broken.**

  You have two distinct `Vector`s -- one for clients, and one for login names.  And you always manage both at the same time.  When you're doing stuff like that, it's generally a clue that you should be grouping that data together somehow.

  But as it stands:

  - They're `static`, so they're shared amongst all the `chatServer`s in existence. But the list/set of connected users is inherently a property of *a* server.  Having them be `static` makes it somewhere between complicated and impossible to have multiple instances.
  - **You don't synchronize access.** So you can end up with names and sockets not correctly matching up, or with the wrong connections being removed, due to race conditions.
  - **You use the login name as a key, but don't enforce uniqueness.**  So there can be two users named "Joe"...but no matter which one sends the logout command, you always log out the *first* one.

  All in all, if you want to keep using the name as a key, get rid of the two vectors and use a `Map<String, AcceptClient>`, where the login name is the key.  But i'd think the server should be more concerned with *connections*, and should care as little about names as possible.

As for suggestions for improvement:

- Pass the port number to `chatServer()`.

  Your code is currently hard-coded to use port 12333. But it's trivial to have that number be a constructor parameter. And from there, it's easy to make it settable from the command line.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Some exceptions, like InterruptedException, were a bit...unfortunately designed.  Catching one almost never means anything bad happened. But since it's a checked exception, it has to be "handled".</sup>